# How can I install cakephp2 in 2022?

Tags: cakephp

can anyone tell me how can I install cakephp 2 in 2022 I tried many ways to install it I also have its zip file which I extract it and when I tried to run it it shows.

Fatal Error
Error: Cannot use 'String' as class name as it is reserved
File: E:\xampp\htdocs\cakephp2.3\lib\Cake\Utility\String.php
Line: 27

Notice: If you want to customize this error message, create app\View\Errors\fatal_error.ctp

Comment: for cakephp 2.x use php5

Answer (score 0):

CakePHP 2 needs php5
since Version 2.8 you can use php70
php71 is possible but you need to install mcrypt seperatly.

Its possible to run a CakePHP 2.8 on php72 with some core hacks. But i wouldn't recommend this.

Answer (score 0):

I got my answer we can download its zip file from github and copy its file in htdocs folder and run it without an issue. By the way I downloaded cakephp 2.10. and it is also running in xampp with php version 8. If in your system it is not running then try to use xampp with php version 7.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).